# Hadoop Relationship between Input Path and Nodes

Tags: hadoop

I'm using FileInputFormat.addInputPath to specify a path to the list of input files for my hadoop job. I've found that if I have x file in my input directory, x mappers will be started over the course of the whole job.

I was wondering if there is any way to specify which input files will correspond to some node, such that I can control which machine will operate on some set of input files.

The reason i'm doing this is because I'm working with a heterogenous cluster, and I want to balance the workload as evenly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, since that would slow down your job significantly. However, you can increase the locality of your tasks by using the Fair Scheduler (due to a technique it uses called "Delay Scheduling"). [This page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.6-alpha/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html#Configuration) has an explanation on the configuration parameters you can modify to achieve a higher locality (at the expense of waiting more for an adequate node); see the `locality.threshold.*` parameters.

See this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681141/hadoop-tasks-not-local-with-file) for more details on the issue of locality in Hadoop. Also, see the "Delay Scheduling" section on the [Hadoop Fair Scheduler design document](http://www.valleytalk.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/fair_scheduler_design_doc.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I was wondering if you have any recommendations as to how I should go about dealing with heterogeneous machines?

The difference in memory and CPU between the varying machines is relatively large, so I do want to avoid running the mappers that take a long time on the slower machines.

Comment: @olshansk You can't avoid them, but speculative execution should take care of your problem. See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164886/hadoop-speculative-task-execution) for more details.